# How to receive zero MySQL-Timestamp-Values

Tags: .net, mysql, nhibernate

Using .Net and NHibernate, I draw Data from a MySql-Database table. This contains a column of data type MySQL-Timestamp with the default zero value (0000-00-00 00:00:00).

I map the column to a DateTime-member of my class. When creating a criteria, NHibernate complains about wrong format. I want to transform the zero values to valid values. Is this possible?

Update:
I have tried to implement the IUserType interface in the class I want to map. However, this doesn´t seem to help much yet. It looks like this:

```
public virtual object NullSafeGet(System.Data.IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        if (rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal(names[6])) || rs.GetDateTime(6) < DateTime.MinValue) return DateTime.MinValue;
        else
            return rs.GetDateTime(6);
    }
```

I have no idea wether this is correct. (The DateTime value that causes problems is the
6th property of the class.)

My program breaks at this code:

```
ISession session = GetCurrentSession(); 
return session.CreateCriteria<ClassToMap>().List<ClassToMap>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have something you'd like to map it to on the MySQL end, and you have control of the query, in your `SELECT` statement you can do something like

```
SELECT IF(field!='0000-00-00 00:00:00',field,'2010-01-01 00:00:00')
FROM table
```

Filling in the `field`, `table`, etc, where `2010-01-01 00:00:00` is what I mapped the zero values to.

Comment: No, I use NHibernate, which does the SQL for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement IUserType and manage MySql return data in the way that you like.

```
// represents conversion on load-from-db operations:   
    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        //Custom Logic
    }
```

Comment: I have tried to implement the IUserType interface in the class I want to map. However, this doesn´t seem to help much yet. My program breaks at this code: ISession session = GetCurrentSession(); return session.CreateCriteria<ClassToMap>().List<ClassToMap>(); <-- here

Comment: you don't have to implement Iusertype in the class you want to map.

Comment: Sorry,you don't have to implement Iusertype in the class you want to map.You must create a public class that implement Iusertype,  and then declare in your map,the property that holds timestamp value as the type you have created.